# TypeScript Extract an array with 10 groups as many as n numbers

Tags: typescript

I have total 62 arrangements as below.

```js
const array = [
  {
    id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2
  },
  ...
  // more 60
]
```

I want to make this arrangement visible only as many as n, leaving only a total of 60 items and removing the rest.

```js
const array = [
  {
    id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3
  },
  {
    id: 4
  },
  {
    id: 5
  },

  ...


  {
    id: 56
  },
  {
    id: 57
  },
  {
    id: 58
  },
  {
    id: 59
  },
  {
    id: 60
  },


  {
    id: 61 // delete
  },
  {
    id: 62 // delete
  },
]
```

So I want to implement a function that finally only imports 60 items.

```
console.log(array.length)
// 60
```

How would you like to implement it's a good idea?
I am using Typescript.

Comment: `array.slice(0, 60)` (new array) or `array.splice(60, array.length - 60)` (modify array in-place)? I’m not sure I understand the question being asked: “_with 10 groups as many as n numbers_”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be to use the [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method, where you can define the start and end index.
But for a proper function make sure you add fallbacks too.
Here is the example code.

```
const getNItemsFromArray = ({array, n}: {array: T[], n: number}) => {
  return array.slice(0, n > array.length ? array.length : n);
}

const firstSixyItems = getNItemsFromArray({array: yourArray, n: 60});
console.log(firstSixyItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you you want to remove array items based on the id `id` property you should filter by that property (assuming all items have a proper continuously increasing `id`) and not use the `Array#length`.

```
const array = [
  {
    id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2
  },
  ...
  // more 60
]

const result = array.filter(item => item.id < 61);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you only want the first 60 items and length of the array is always going to be greater than 60 then you can do like this

```
array.length = 60;
```